# how to disable dropdown selection?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a dropdown with 2 options:

[image]

I want the user to be able to see both options (Cips, Projects); however, I do not want to allow the user to choose a different item.

**How do we allow the user to click on the dropdown and see all the options, but disable choosing any other option?**

This dropdown is defined like so:

```
      <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editRagColumns.BaseObjectType"
             name="RagBasicType"
             type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="RagBasicType"
             [options]="baseObjectTypes"
             optionLabel="BaseObjectTypeName"
             [style]="{'width':'100%', 'border-color':'transparent'}"
                  >
        </p-dropdown>
```

Comment: Try adding:
optionDisabled

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown

You can use this `optionDisabled`

Comment: no luck https://i.imgur.com/3Z8kN4V.gif

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following property to your "p-dropdown" component.

```
optionDisabled="BaseObjectTypeName"
```

This is my ts and html file that I have done to confirm that it works.

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question1',
  templateUrl: './question1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question1.component.sass']
})
export class Question1Component implements OnInit {

  BaseObjectTypeName: string = "BaseObjectTypeName";

  baseObjectTypes: any[] = [
    { BaseObjectTypeName: "tab1" },
    { BaseObjectTypeName: "tab2" },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**html file**

```
<p-dropdown
  name="RagBasicType"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  id="RagBasicType"
  [options]="baseObjectTypes"
  optionLabel="BaseObjectTypeName"
  [style]="{'width':'100%', 'border-color':'transparent'}"
  optionDisabled="BaseObjectTypeName"
>
</p-dropdown>
```

I hope I've helped you.

Comment: no luck https://i.imgur.com/3Z8kN4V.gif

Comment: Have you tried using my code and change it a bit to detect with is the line which is generating the bug?
If you copy & paste my code, you should see that the functionality is working and, starting from there, you can change my code with yours, until you detect that bug has appeared.

If you don't find the problem and you can pass your ts code, maybe I can find the problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zbt9Dc0
This is the gif with the result of my code

Answer (score 1):

If you are using primeng `11.0.0` and onwards, then `optionDisabled` property is the way to go, as others have already mentioned.

In case if you are using previous versions, then you have to ensure following points:

- The value passed to `options` must be of [SelectItem[ ]](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/c7d38b369af81217fe0be73a619b2c3f41940ebc/src/app/components/api/selectitem.ts) type or at least have `label`, `value` and `disabled` properties from SelectItem type.

  - `label` would be the dropdown option text
  - `value` can be of any type i.e an object or simply a string
  - `disabled` would be of boolean type, setting it to `true` will disable the dropdown option
- p-dropdown `optionLabel` should not be used

In your case `baseObjectTypes` should be something as below:

```ts
    baseObjectTypes = [
      { label: 'Projects', value: 'Projects', disabled: true },  // <--- value can be object too
      { label: 'Cips', value: 'Cips', disabled: true 
    ]
```